# WQL for REF properties: PowerShell vs C#

Tags: c#, powershell, wql

The simple query works fine in PowerShell:

```
gwmi -Query "select * from Win32_DependentService where Antecedent='\\\\MYPC\\root\\cimv2:Win32_SystemDriver.Name=`"WdFilter`"'"
```

but it doesn't work in C#:

```
var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\MYPC\\Root\\Cimv2");
scope.Connect();
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_DependentService where Antecedent = '\\\\MYPC\\root\\cimv2:Win32_SystemDriver.Name=\"WdFilter\"'"));
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
var count = queryCollection.Count; // "Invalid query" exception here!!!
```

What is wrong with C# query?
Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting or just no results? If you getting exception it could be formatting problem. Try using String.Format to generate the query string.

Comment: It is exception. "Invalid query" exception (see comment in the last code line). String.Format .. Hmm What is an idea for that? I just made copy&paste query string from the PS and replaced escape sequence for nested (") char.

Comment: I mean you might think escaping works sometimes but it may not be what you think. Try to escape the second `=` as well and see.

Comment: escaping second = doesn't work as well. Moreover I see quite good query string in the debugger: "select * from Win32_DependentService where Antecedent = '\\MYPC\root\cimv2:Win32_SystemDriver.Name="WdFilter"'

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! We need more backslashes (up to eight! :). Right code is:

```
var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\MYPC\\Root\\Cimv2");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_DependentService where Antecedent='\\\\\\\\MYPC\\\\root\\\\cimv2:Win32_SystemDriver.Name=\"WdFilter\"'"));
var queryCollection = searcher.Get();
var count = queryCollection.Count; // it's OK now
```

Hope it helps to somebody else :)